# Jquery function gets 'Error: DevTools failed to load SourceMap' causing infinite refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This code is running in a chrome extension. I'm using jquery to replace one word within HTML elements and the code works fine on every website I visit except google searches (the google homepage loads fine though).

When I google normal phrases I get infinite refreshing of the page with the error `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for extension`. If I google something containing the word 'test_word', it gives me a `Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 30ms` and then the same `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for` error, but the infinite refreshing does not occur.

Here is the code causing the error:

```
$('*', document).addBack().contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 3) {
            var u = this.nodeValue;
            var reg = /test_word/ig;
            $(this).replaceWith(u.replace(reg,'different_word'));
        }
    });
```

I'm don't have much experience with DOM manipulation so not really sure what those errors mean or what could be triggering the infinite refreshing on google searches, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the replacement of word (with different string length) changes the layout of content hence it causes the refreshment. You can try to replace the word with exact same length to see if the problem still insists.

Comment: Why would changing the layout of content cause a refresh, and why would that only happen on certain sites? Is it a setting I can disable?

Comment: This is just a assumption.That's why I suggest try to replace the word with same length so in this case the layout shall not change. If the problem does not insist then you can confirm that's the problem, otherwise it's some other issues that I don't know without some investment by myself.

Answer (score -1):

You should turn off your Chrome extension. We got that error just because of the extension failing to load.

Comment: It was worked for me.